# Is there a devanagari or Hindu numerology / gematria?

Tags: sanskrit, mathematics, numerology

Searching for devanagari numerology, you find stuff like [this](https://www.occultspeak.com/numerology-calculator/) which hints at a system. But is there a system, for mapping numbers to the devanagari/sanskrit characters/sounds in Hinduism anywhere to be found? If so, where can I find it, and/or what are the numerical mappings to the characters?

Comment: Aryabhat has used that and there are more than 5 systems

Comment: > https://youtu.be/8e5yyysiFeg This video explains what you want the enumeration of letters, And this however is more centric to ancient mathematics

Comment: Any links please?